# Is Customizing My Sites in SharePoint 2010 Allowed?

Tags: my-site

I've heard that Microsoft doesn't support customizations made to the SharePoint 2007 My Sites.  Is this the same for 2010?  What is supported in Customizing SharePoint 2010 My Sites?

Answer (score 3):

No it's not unsupported to customize any page in SharePoint. You should of course not customize the actual file in the SharePoint root, but instead customize the page in the site (using Web UI or SharePoint Designer 2010).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a custom person.aspx page?  I've never heard of that being unsupported and I seem to recall EA Games being a case study from MIcrosoft on how the My Sites can be turned into a company social experience for users, or something to that affect.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about modifying the person.aspx page.  I've read in several other blogs that this is not supported in 2007.  We have had a vendor customize our 2007 MySites regardless (to remove web parts and remove users ownership permissions) this has caused considerable issues and I'd like some ammunition to our governance board not to do this again.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to create a solution in Visual Studio and make a feature of the design and activate your changes through this.
In a backup disaster plan, this is preferable ..

I have created a small codeplex project for this:
http://grauersmasterfeature.codeplex.com/